# Rails undefined method * for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am having an issue and I have done some reasearch, from my research I have found that the variable that is being used is empty, however I am unsure as to why it is empty, Maybe its something obvious to someone else?

I am trying to display a nested form on a page from another controller, I am used nested resources, Which I think might be my issue, but unsure how to resolve it.

**Getting the following error:**

```
undefined method `submission' for nil:NilClass
```

Structure of Project 
Main Folders
-Members 
--Questions
--Submissions

**Concept:**

Question - has_many - Submissions
Submission - Belongs_to - Question

**Submission Model:**

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :member
end
```

**Question Model:**

```
class Members::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
end
```

**Submissions Controller:**

```
def create

        @question =  Members::Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @submission.member_id =  current_member.id
        @submission = @question.submissions.create(params[:submission].permit(:content, :question_id))

*Redirect Method Here * 

end
```

In the form I am using the following method:

```
<%= form_for([@question, @question.submission.build]) do |f| %>
  <% if @submission.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@submission.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this submission from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @submission.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then to display the form on the show page of the question, I am using

```
<%= render 'members/submissions/form' %>
```

**Routes:**

```
  namespace :members do
    resources :questions,  only: [:index,:show] do
      resources :submissions 
    end
  end
```

Any one any ideas where I am going wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is your controller returning an object here ? `@question =  Members::Question.find(params[:question_id])` .. do a `@question.inspect` after that line to find out

Comment: You have typo in the view `@question.submission.build` should be `@question.submissions.build`

Comment: @MikDiet I have tried both, neither work.

Comment: @sa77 I have tried this, but not seeing any output on the website or the in the terminal, where would I expect to see an output?

Comment: @user7391609 on which line it is throwing the error?

Comment: you can do `<%= @question.inspect %>` on the view page which you are redirecting the action at the end of that create action in `SubmissionsController`

Comment: I am trying to display the "Submissions" form on the "Questions" view, But when I open the "Show" method or browse the question's show page, Is when I get the error.

Comment: You say the problem is the `show` page  so can you show the `def show` from your QuestionsController? And the `show` view?  Also your `create` method doesn't make sense to me... you have `@submission.member_id = ...` *before* you define `@submission`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, Thank you for the suggestions, I was using the wrong variable, I was using @question, When because its nested, the correct variable is @members_question

Submissions Controller

```
def create

        @members_question =  Members::Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @submission = @members_question.submissions.create(params[:submission].permit(:content, :question_id))
    @submission.member_id =  current_member.id

end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@members_question, @members_question.submissions.build]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The name of the variable is absolutely irrelevant, it just has to match in the controller and in the form.